# Accessing Home page settings of phone's web browser from an app

Tags: android, browser, bookmarks

Can I access the Home / Bookmarks settings of the user's web browser from my Android app? Basically what I need to achieve is that I should be able to open the browser from my app and show the Home page set by the user as the default page. Right now I'm using ,

Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
   startActivity(i);

But actually what I want is to open the Home page set by the user instead of opening Google by default. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I access the Home / Bookmarks settings of the user's web browser from my Android app?

If the particular app uses the `Browser` provider, you can access those bookmarks, assuming that you hold the proper permission. The user's default browser may or may not use this provider, and there is no obvious way to tell which bookmark is the "home page", assuming the browser even has a concept of a "home page".